# Configuring Drupal 6.20 to display a different icon in a specific region on a specific group of pages

Tags: 6, blocks, media, theming

I've added a block called 'Course Information', configured the block to display on a particular group of pages (courses/full-time/*). This works fine, but I don't know to configure Drupal to display a different icon for each of the pages.

At present, the block contains:

```
<img alt="An icon symbol" src="/sites/default/files/images/icon-1.png" />
```

This will display the same image on each page that the block is used. How would I go about having a dynamic filename inserted, like icon-2.png, icon-3.png, icon-n.png?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is being displayed on nodes you can add an imagefield to the content type and set its display settings to excluded. Then make a views block that displays the image field, using a default argument of the current node.

Comment: Jody, thanks for your help. I added a field to the page content type called 'course_icon' and excluded the field from display, but I'm having trouble implementing a working view to display it. Any idea where I'm going wrong? Here's a copy of the view: http://pastebin.com/WVmQ5sai

Comment: It looks like you're using a relationship to use image module, but then you're also using an imagefield field. You can likely remove the relationship. But the real problem is your argument. Your argument should be node:nid, and under 'action to take if argument is not present' you choose 'provide default argument', 'node id from url'.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I shall investigate your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP-code inside your block, and use the [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6) function to solve it like

```
 print '<img alt="An icon symbol" src="/sites/default/files/images/icon-' . arg(2) . '.png" />'
```

This depends on the * behind full-time. It would be better to use an extra function with a mapping (* => int), and validation inside your theme or a module.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Where should the above code be placed? Can you provide step-by-step instructions to implement this? In what respect does this solution depend on what's behind the courses/full-time/*? The content type of these nodes are all pages.

Comment: You can change the input format of the block containing the img to "PHP code". The arg() function returns parts of the url. So the output depends on your aliases. From api.drupal.org: _When viewing a page at the path "admin/content/types", for example, arg(0) would return "admin", arg(1) would return "content", and arg(2) would return "types"._